# how to read python object using langchain python agent [reproducible example]

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import openai
import os
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits import create_python_agent
from langchain_experimental.tools import PythonREPLTool

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

my_name = "tom"

agent_executor_openAI = create_python_agent(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4-1106-preview"),
    tool=PythonREPLTool(locals = {"my_name":my_name}),
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
    agent_executor_kwargs={"handle_parsing_errors": True},
)
agent_executor_openAI.run("print out the python object 'my_name'")
```

this is the output

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Invoking: `Python_REPL` with `my_name = 'Agent' print(my_name)`

Agent
The output of the python object 'my_name' is 'Agent'.

> Finished chain.
> "The output of the python object 'my_name' is 'Agent'."

My question is how to get it to correctly output "Tom"

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable name and appropriate  variable names。

```
agent_executor_openAI = create_python_agent(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4-1106-preview"),
    tool=PythonAstREPLTool(locals = {"my_name":my_name}),
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    agent_executor_kwargs={"handle_parsing_errors": True},
)
agent_executor_openAI.run("print(my_name)")
```